# How do I create a facebook test user for a website?

Tags: web, facebook-like, html, facebook-test-users

I have facebook like buttons on web pages. I want to test the buttons using a facebook account. I know you can create test users to test a facebook app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/), but the directions and GUI seem to be targeted only at Facebook apps. The web site is associated with a facebook page for the organization, but the admin controls don't include the Facebook App Developer controls, like the GUI for test users. This is what the roles page looks like for our Facebook page:

[image: roles page screenshot]

I want to be able to like pages on the site so I can make sure that Facebook gets the right title, url, and description for the resulting posts created when a user clicks the like button. How can I create test users to do this?

The like button is created using AddThis if that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

That's a screenshot of the page management interface - you need to create test users for your app via the API or app dashboard, not via the page interface: full documentation here: developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users

The test user will be tied to the app ID that owns it, but test users can use multiple apps too